# sapui5 Not able to display data in detail page

Tags: sapui5

I have a problem to display data in my detail page. I've tried almost everything but its dosnt work. On main page everything looks fine. Routing work (display proper ID on network address).

Details.controller.js :

```
return Controller.extend("sapProject.controller.Details", {
        onInit: function () {
            var oTable = this.getView().byId("details");
            var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
            oModel.loadData("model/Object.json");
            oTable.setModel(oModel);
  var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
  oRouter.getRoute("Details").attachMatched(this._onRouteMatched, this);
},

        _onRouteMatched : function (oEvent) {
  var oArgs, oView;
  oArgs = oEvent.getParameter("arguments");
  oView = this.getView();
  oView.bindElement({
    path : "/Objects(" + oArgs.employeeId + ")",
    events : {
      dataRequested: function () {
        oView.setBusy(true);
      },
      dataReceived: function () {
        oView.setBusy(false);
      }
    }
  });
},
```

and this is my Details.view.xml:

```
    <Page
        id="details"

        title="{i18n>EmployeeDetailsOf} {FirstName} {LastName}"
        showNavButton="true"
        navButtonPress="onBack"
        class="sapUiResponsiveContentPadding">
        <content>
            <Panel

                width="auto"
                class="sapUiResponsiveMargin sapUiNoContentPadding">
                <headerToolbar >
                    <Toolbar>
                        <Title text="{i18n>EmployeeIDColon} {EmployeeID}" level="H2"/>
                        <ToolbarSpacer />
                    </Toolbar>
                </headerToolbar>
                <content>
                    <f:SimpleForm>
                        <f:content>
                            <Label text="{i18n>FirstName}" />
                            <Text text="{FirstName}" />
                            <Label text="{i18n>LastName}" />
                        </f:content>
                    </f:SimpleForm>
                </content>
            </Panel>
        </content>
    </Page>
```

Comment: Do you have any error messages in console?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are binding an empty model to your detail view because probably the `loadData` function is not completed when you set the model on the Table.

Try to load your json file in the manifest (best option) or differ the `setModel` on the `_onRouteMatched` function (although I don't see any table in your detail view).

EDIT:
You can also use this code after oModel.loadData("model/Object.json");

```
oModel.attachEventOnce("requestCompleted", function(oEvent) {       
  // Here your file is fully loaded     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I recommend you to bind like this:

```
var sObjectPath = this.getModel().createKey("Objects", {
            ID: oArgs.employeeId
        });
        this._bindView("/" + sObjectPath);
...
}


_bindView: function (sObjectPath) {
            //Todo: Set busy indicator during view binding

            this.getView().bindElement({
                path: sObjectPath,
                parameters: {

                },
                events: {
                    change: this._onBindingChange.bind(this),
                    dataRequested: function () {

                    }.bind(this),
                    dataReceived: function () {

                    }.bind(this)
                }
            });
        },
```

Secondly check if oArgs.employeeId has a valid value and also if the model is loaded with data, easily set a brekapoint or write console.log(this.getView().getModel().oData).